# How to set cursor on the end of line after Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#

I want to keep cursor for more inputs on the same line when user inputs data to the console.

Inputs:

```
1   123   12332
```

not:

```
1
123
12332
```

Comment: Can you not use Console.Read()?

Comment: Have you looked at the SetCursor functionality?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx

    Console.SetCursorPosition(origCol+x, origRow+y);

Comment: Im sorry
1 123 12332

1\n 123\n 12332\n

Comment: @dwatland You almost certainly mean `ReadKey`, not `Read`.  `Read` reads in a whole line and then gives you the first character, rather than waiting for only a single character and giving it to you right away.

Comment: Console.Read() reads a first symbol .

Comment: Are you saying that you want to stay on the same line even after the user hits the 'Enter' button?

Comment: **Input** - not *imput* ....

Comment: Rufus L ,yes this is what I want ,thanks.

Comment: @Servey: Console.ReadKey, interesting. Didn't know it. Is it guaranteed to work e.g. under Linux? Does the runtime set the terminal's line discipline so that the application can see single keystrokes?

Comment: @PeterSchneider I have no idea what the mono implementation does for that method.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. Basically, it asks the user to input 10 numbers, and after each input it resets the cursor position to one space after the last input:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Change this if you want more or less space between inputs
    const int numberOfSpacesBetweenInputs = 1;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter 10 numbers and hit enter between each one:");

    // This list will hold valid numbers input by user
    var numbers = new List<int>();

    int temp;
    var inputLength = 0;

    while (numbers.Count < 10)
    {
        // Get input from the user
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        // We keep track of the length of the user input, and add 
        // however many spaces we want between entries
        inputLength += input.Length + numberOfSpacesBetweenInputs;

        // If the input length is longer than the console buffer,
        // reset it so it wraps to the next line
        inputLength = inputLength % Console.BufferWidth;

        // Use TryParse, so we only add valid numbers.
        if (int.TryParse(input, out temp)) numbers.Add(temp);

        // Reset cursor position
        Console.SetCursorPosition(inputLength, Console.CursorTop - 1);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nThank you. The valid entries are:\n\n{0}", 
        string.Join(", ", numbers));

    Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```